# Android: How to remove the Wifi Network by using removeNetwork() correctly (Android 5.0 Asus Zenfone )

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

First, I'm using the addNetwork() to add a SSID to the Configuration list. Everything is okay(SSID has been added to the Configuration list successfully).

Second, I'm using removeNetwork() to remove the configured network. When I execute this method, everything acts as it should. The wifi disconnects and the SSID doe not appear in the list of configured netowrks...

But, when I using the addNetwork() to add the same SSID to the Configuration list again.
I always get the return value(networkId) -1.

The only way to solve this problem is to restart the WiFi function.

Comment: "same SSID"... What do you mean by same SSID the one you first added and then removed? Are you adding and removing the same SSID? If yes, what is the need for adding and removing it because you are never connecting to it?

Comment: Problem is with Android 5.0 and above, that removeNetwork() method in no more capable to remove the wifi networks.